# how to apply tailwind to particular folder in svelte

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, svelte, tailwind-in-js

I have a specific component that i want to exclude from being styled by Tailwind.

I have tried adding the component's class name to the excluded array in your tailwind.config.js file.

like this :

```
`content: ['./src/lib/**/*.svelte', './src/routes/Header.svelte'], `
`excluded: './src/routes/Header.svelte' `
```

and also tried  `important: true`,  or  `important: '#app'`

but it didn't work.
want to know how to properly exclude a specific component from Tailwind styles in Svelte project

Comment: Just don't use Tailwind classes in your component and overwrite the tailwind defaults in the style tag of the component? Not sure if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exclude option in Tailwind anymore but you can use a `!` to exclude a file or folder in the content.

```
`content: ['./src/lib/**/*.svelte', '!./src/routes/Header.svelte']`
```